# conversion from 'KanjiCard*' to non-scalar type 'KanjiCard' requested (custom enum)

Tags: c++, c, enums, g++

Okay, I've tried using Google-sensei and searching around on this website, and while I've found many posts about this error, I haven't found any that have addressed enums. Also, all the ones I have seen have either been someone trying to assign one type to another, improper use of 'new', etc. As far as I can tell, that's not the case in this instance.

As stated in the title, I'm getting an error `conversion from 'KanjiCard*' to non-scalar type 'KanjiCard' requested` when trying to compile the program I'm working on using g++.

I have a class named KanjiCard that has this publicly-defined enum:

```
enum KanjiCardType {
    KANJI_CARD = 1,
    KEYWORD_CARD = 2
};
```

The constructor for the class is defined as follows:

```
    KanjiCard(char *cardText, int cardTextLength, int cardWidth, int cardHeight,
        int cardX, int cardY, KanjiCardType cardType, SDL_Color textColor);
```

(I'm using char* instead of std::string because it's easier to work with the libraries I'm using that way.)

I'm calling it to create new cards like so (this is where the error comes up):

```
KanjiCard currentCard = new KanjiCard(kanji_line, strlen(kanji_line), 
    CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, xPos, yPos, cardType, textColor);
```

`cardType` is defined as such: `KanjiCard::KanjiCardType cardType = KanjiCard::KANJI_CARD;`

I originally tried just passing in `KanjiCard::KANJI_CARD` where `cardType` is in that constructor call right now, but I got that error, so I've been trying everything I could think of to try and get it to work, including trying switching the `cardType` parameter in the constructor to `*cardType` and `&cardType` and messing around with the type of `cardType` in the call as well, to no avail.

As far as I can tell, `cardType` isn't a pointer, so I really can't figure out why I'm getting that message. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm at my wit's end trying to figure this out.

**Edit:** I should also mention that I also tried pulling the enum out of the class (and removing the `KanjiCard::` preface, of course), and still had the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `cardType` that's the problem; it's `currentCard`. You wrote this:

```
KanjiCard currentCard = new KanjiCard(...
```

That's assigning a pointer to a non-pointer type. You may have meant this:

```
KanjiCard *currentCard = new KanjiCard(...
```

...or you may have meant this:

```
KanjiCard currentCard(...
```

The former of my suggestions will allocate a `KanjiCard` on the heap. `currentCard` will point to the `KanjiCard`. The latter will allocate it on the stack. It *is* a `KanjiCard`.

The former you'll have to manually `delete`. The latter doesn't need to be `delete`d; it is valid within the scope it's declared and once it goes out of scope, it's invalid.

The former you can access members of using `->`. The latter you can access members of using `.`.

Comment: ( **facepalms and laughs** ) Yes. that would probably be it. xD Thank you for catching that for me. That'll teach me to code when I'm tired. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
KanjiCard currentCard = KanjiCard(
    kanji_line, strlen(kanji_line), CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, xPos, yPos, cardType, textColor
    );
```

or

```
KanjiCard currentCard(
    kanji_line, strlen(kanji_line), CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT, xPos, yPos, cardType, textColor
    );
```

The first is called *copy initialization*, and the second is called *direct initialization*.

Note that there is no `new` here.

Cheers & hth.,