# Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, header, linker, declaration

I am getting a [Linker Error] undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' and I am unable to fix the issue. I am using Dev-C++ - In my project settings 'Win32 Console' is selected as I want it to be a console application.

Example Header (Test.h):

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Test {
  private:
    int testing;
  public:
    int main();
};
#endif
```

Example .cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;
int Test::main(){ 
   /*         EXAMPLE       */
   cout << "Enter Test" <<endl;
   cin >> testing;
   cout << "----------------------------"<<endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;   
}
```

I can fix the error by removing the `Test::` in front of the main() but I want it to reference my header file. If it does not reference my header file all of my variables become undeclared.. unless I put them into the program itself.

Please note the code is only an example of what I am doing.. and sorry once again if it's stupidly obvious. :-(

Comment: `main` must be a free function.

Comment: Putting main inside a class looks very much like Java.  :-(  You can try having *both* a member function and a global function, `int main() { return Test::main(); }`.

Comment: The "main" of your program should be "in no namespace". Adding `Test::` to main will make it into a completely different function - just like calling it `MatsMain` or `kerflunk` would not work. It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here, but it's clear that you need to have a `main` without namespace SOMEWHERE in your code. That can then create a `Test` object, and call `main` in that class, if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers are provided in the comments themselves, but here is the gist::

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Test {
  private:
    int testing;
  public:
    int main();
};

int Test::main(){ 
   /*         EXAMPLE       */
   cout << "Enter Test" <<endl;
   cin >> testing;
   cout << "----------------------------"<<endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;   
}
#endif
```

And in the .cpp file::

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){ 
   /*         EXAMPLE       */
   Test *testObject = new Test();
   testObject->main();
   delete(testObject);
   system("pause");
   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your solution, however it is giving me a 'conversion from 'class' to non-scalar type 'class' requested' error.

I thought it may have to be main() on its own but never knew you could create a function inside a header file. I have inputs (cin), outputs (cout), if statements, while loops in the main().. not sure if this will cause any problems.

The program itself was running before I tried to improve it using header files! Making the transition from Java to C++ has been a nightmare so far! :-(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062113/conversion-from-kanjicard-to-non-scalar-type-kanjicard-requested-custom-en , making the change now

Comment: O wow, it was really that simple? Ouch sorry about that man! Thanks very much its compiled and running now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, and why are you using `system("PAUSE")`, when there is a much better way!? (You can read here as to why `system()` is evil: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/ )
Why not go with something like this:

```
void PressEnterToContinue()
{
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...\n";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

and then call the function at the end??